# Go - initialize an empty slice

Tags: memory, go, slice, allocation, is-empty

To declare an empty slice, I know that you should prefer

```
var t []string
```

over

```
t := []string{}
```

as it doesn't allocate unecessary memory (https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/CodeReviewComments#declaring-empty-slices). Does this still apply if I have

```
type example struct {
    s []string
}
e := &example{}
```

i.e. would it be better to use

```
e.s = []string{}
```

or

```
var s []string
e.s = s
```

Comment: Your last example does nothing, as `example.s` is already a nil slice of the correct type. You don't need to do anything in this case.

Comment: sorry - edited my question. still true?

Comment: I got what you meant even though the code was invalid. `e.s` and `s` are both `nil`, so all you are doing is assigning `e.s = nil` which does nothing. `e.s` is already the correct type, so there's nothing you need to do.

Comment: https://play.golang.org/p/9C_bnsrIeU

Comment: awesome, thanks @JimB

Answer (score 2):

`example.s` is already declared, so there's nothing you need to do.

```
e := &example{}
e.s = append(e.s, "val")
fmt.Println(e.s)
```